# HttpClient.SendAsync - The text associated with this error code could not be found. '': Invalid characters found

Tags: c#, odata, dotnet-httpclient

HttpClient.SendAsync or PostAsync is throwing below error.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Exception: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>
> '': Invalid characters found.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpHandlerToFilter.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancel)
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
> at TestApp.MainPage.PostRequest(String url, StringContent stringContent)

Here is the C# Code:

```
    var address = new AddressModel()
            {
                CommunicationId = "email@domain.com",
                ......
            };
var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(address), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                          .Accept
                          .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", AuthCookie);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "X");
                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)
                    {
                        Content = stringContent//CONTENT-TYPE header
                    };

                        try
                        {
                            //Failing on this Line. 
                            responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
                            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var responseContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //
                        }
```

Infact, the Post call was successful and response code was 201-created if we observe it in fiddler. but the Json response the post call is returning is causing the error and hence PostAsync is failing to prepare HttpResponseMessage object.

I don't see any issue with the response JSON pasted below which could cause - invalid characters found.

Providing both the Raw request and response.

```
POST http://host/sap/opu/odata/sap/EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS_SRV/ADDRESS_ODATA HTTP/1.1
Cookie: MYSAPSSO2=---------;
X-Requested-With: X
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 619
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: host:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

    {"start_date":"20090704","emailid":"email@domain.com","pernr":"123456","subty":"2","begda":"\/Date(1246838400000)\/","endda":"\/Date(1561950000000)\/","stext":"Home","name2":"Xyz","stras":"Address line one","locat":"Address line two","anssa":"1","grpvl":"1","land1":"IN","hsnmr":"2-3","landx50":"India","state":"10","bezei":"Karnataka","ort02":"fsd","ort01":"Bengaluru","entkm":"0","pstlz":"560097","telnr":"1234567890","persg":null,"persk":null,"bukrs":"safs","ename":"afjdsklfsl","persa":null,"molga":null,"country":null,"name1":"asfsd","comp_code":"ABC","emp_curr":"INR","message":"Sample"}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
set-cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-client=300; path=/
set-cookie: SAP_SESSIONID_DHR_100=asjkfhskdhfks%3d; path=/
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 1117
location: http://host:8080/sap/opu/odata/sap/EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS_SRV/ADDRESS_ODATA(emailid='email@domain.com',pernr='123456',subty='2',seqnr='000',start_date='20090704')
dataserviceversion: 2.0
message type: S
custom message: Home has been created successfully
sap-processing-info: ODataBEP=,crp=,st=,MedCacheHub=SHM,codeployed=X,softstate=
sap-perf-fesrec: 232519.000000

    {"d":{"__metadata":{"id":"http://host:8080/sap/opu/odata/sap/EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS_SRV/ADDRESS_ODATA(emailid='email@domain.com',pernr='123456',subty='2',seqnr='000',start_date='20090704')","uri":"http://host:8080/sap/opu/odata/sap/EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS_SRV/ADDRESS_ODATA(emailid='email@domain.com',pernr='123456',subty='2',seqnr='000',start_date='20090704')","type":"EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS_SRV.ADDRESS_ODATAType"},"emailid":"email@domain.com","pernr":"123456","subty":"2","seqnr":"000","start_date":"20090704","begda":"\/Date(1246838400000)\/","endda":"\/Date(1561939200000)\/","stext":"Home","stras":"Address line one","locat":"Address line two","anssa":"1","grpvl":"1","name2":"Xyz","hsnmr":"2-3","ort01":"Bengaluru","ort02":"fsd","pstlz":"560097","land1":"IN","landx50":"India","telnr":"1234567890","entkm":"0","state":"10","bezei":"Karnataka","persg":"","persk":"","bukrs":"safs","ename":"afjdsklfsl","persa":"","molga":"","country":"","name1":"asfsd","comp_code":"WST","emp_curr":"INR","message":"Sample"}}
```

Comment: Why is the response body indented? Are there possibly non-printing UTF characters in there? To troubleshoot the problem, try reading the body yourself and deserializing the JSON in a separate step.

Comment: @John - added the C# Code now. and it is failing on this line 
                            responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);

Comment: @JohnWu - it is failing at httpClient.SendAsync itself. if I get the HttpResponseMessage object, I can try to parse with custom/dynamic object.

Comment: @NareshPodishetty why do you assume `SendAsync` failed? There was no error in the response, the code you posted actually *hides* exceptions from `SendAsync` and the snippet you posted is typically raised by UWP applications. Post the *actual* exception, not just part of it

Comment: Please post the full exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Post the actual code that throws the exception, and the *full* exception text, not just the first line of the message. It's quite likely that the error wasn't caused by `SendAsyn`. You can get the full text easily with `Exception.ToString()`. The full text contains any inner exceptions and the call stack that points to the exact method that threw and the chain of calls that lead to it. Post the full exception, not just the call stack or just the inner exceptions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - it is going to catch block from SendAsync saying invalid characters. The response i posted is from the fiddler it captured while i debug SendAsync with this request.

Comment: @NareshPodishetty instead of explaining the code, post the actual exception text. The code you posted wouldn't throw that message. There's no error in the response.

Comment: I am upvoting this question because man that is one bizarre exception.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Posted the full exception message along with stack trace

Comment: Just a hunch. Do you have WCF tracing enabled?  Maybe the filter config has an issue?  The faulty string might not be the HTTP response itself with some other string that have to be validated during the handling of the response, such as a setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for responding and providing suggestions.

The issue was with the response header properties

```
message type: S
custom message: Home has been created successfully
```

key's has space in them. after changing them to **message-type** and **custom-message** with hiphen instead of space - it worked fine.